# Restrict a user to visit a particular page only certain number of times

Tags: drupal

How to restrict a user (role) to visit a particular page only certain number of times?

I am using drupal 6. It's for premium content, I just want to give 5 premium content free.

Comment: If you describe your own attempts to solve this problem, you'll have a bigger chance to get an answer.

Comment: Enable statistic module and then use access table in order to get the number of visits by a user. After certain visits, check in node view and restrict the access!

Comment: Are you going to code this solution or just in search for 3rd party contribs?

Answer (score 2):

you can count the number of visits of a user for that page, and update the count in Cookie or Session variable, if the visits are greater then the defined limit, redirect the page to some other page, 
some on load hook can be invoked to count the visits,

Answer (score 0):

Not tried this but you can use Content Profile and rules modules to do this. Create a field in the user profile to keep track of the count. Use the rules module to check if the user is viewing the premium content page and if he is viewing, just before rendering the page check for the user profile count. if less than 5 increment the count else if more then redirect.